# How to escape '>' character in markdown

Tags: markdown

I have for example this sintax >45 which markdown has transformed it in:

[image]

I use a markdown library and in

**escape** : /^\[\`*_{}[]()#+.!-]/

I try to add the > but not working

**escape** : /^\[\`*_{}[]()#+.!>-]/

I want the expression >45 still >45 after applying markdown.

Update with solution:
In markdown library I added followind code in `blockquote` function:
`var myRegex = new RegExp("^>.+"); 
  if ( !block.match( /^>/m ) || block.match(myRegex)) 
        return undefined;`

Comment: What markdown library are you using?

Comment: markdown.js from Christoph Dorn [link] (https://github.com/cadorn/markdown-js/blob/master/lib/markdown.js)

Answer (score 2):

The bit of code I assume you are referring to is line 796:

```
if ( text.match( /^\\[\\`\*_{}\[\]()#\+.!\-]/ ) )
```

To escape the > character try changing it to:

```
if ( text.match( /^\\[\\`\*_{}\[\]()#\+.!\->]/ ) )
```

That string there is a regex, you should probably learn about it, they are very useful.

But do that as a last resort, have you tried just typing:

```
\> text
```

instead?